# How to read from stdin using dpkt.pcap.Reader?

Tags: python-2.7, usb, pcap, dpkt

I'm currently trying to analyse incoming USB traffic using USBPcap + Python/dpkt, with an optical USB-mouse as an example input device.

After launching batch file containing the command

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap7 -o - | pipetest.py
```

the following code works perfectly:

```
# pipetest.py
# sniffing for USB-mouse activities
import sys
import dpkt, struct

try:
    f = open('c:\\users\\user\\downloads\\test.pcap','wb')
    while True:
        inpt = sys.stdin.read(34)        # package length
        f.write(inpt)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   f.close()

f = open('c:\\users\\user\\downloads\\test.pcap','rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
print

for ts, buf in pcap:
    data = struct.unpack("b"*7, buf[-7:]) # 7-byte leftover with mouse info
    print data 

f.close()
```

Output is:

```
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
^C
(3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  <---|
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)      |
(3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  <---|
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)      |------ Four clicks with mouse wheel
(3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  <---|
(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)      |
(3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  <---|
(0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 7)
```

Unfortunately, I've got a problem with LIVE analysis of captured data. How can I get dpkt.pcap.Reader() to work with ***sys.stdin*** instead of open('foo.pcap')?

P.S. I surely can do

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap2 -o - | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -
```

as shown in [official mini-tutorial](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/tour.html) but I would like to perform real-time USB traffic using USB sniffer + Python.

P.P.S. Python/PyUSB + libusb-win32 works perfectly but I do need USBPcap! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **named pipe** *(FIFO buffer)* for this ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows )  see [createNamedPipe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319679/createnamedpipe-in-python) and [Windows named pipes in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077145/windows-named-pipes-in-practice)

you create the named pipe, open `USBpcap` from within your python program and pipe the output to the named pipe you just created ([How to Run an .exe File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849868/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-python), [how to run an exe file with the arguments using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928956/how-to-run-an-exe-file-with-the-arguments-using-python)), then you read from the named pipe with `dpkt.pcap.Reader()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx